# pthread third argument in c language

Tags: c, multithreading

i'd like to create threads

```
int joueur=3;  // in my case it is in a "for" loop
jouer(joueur);
```

I used this syntax

I have tried with this:

```
int *joueur = malloc(sizeof(*joueur));
//if (joueur == NULL)
    //doNotStartTheThread_ProblemAllocatingMemory();
pthread_create(&threads[joueur], NULL, jouer, (int *) joueur); 

jouer function

void jouer(int joueur)
 {
 while(but_trouve==0)
  {
  pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);   
  for(joueur=0;joueur<nombre_joueurs;joueur++) if(labyrinthe[joueur_ligne[joueur]][(joueur_colonne[joueur])%4]="b") but_trouve=1;   
  if (but_trouve==1) break; // si un joueur a trouve le but on termine la partie
  deplacer(joueur);
//  pthread_cond_signal (&condition); /* On délivre le signal : condition remplie */
  pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);  // Fin de la zone protegee 
  affiche(); 
  }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
 }
```

But i have this message now.

```
 warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  pthread_create(&threads[threads[nombre_joueurs]], NULL, jouer, (int *) joueur);
In file included from /home/nouha/test.c:4:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:244:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(int)’
 extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
```

,  Thank you for reading,

Comment: Well, what type is the third argument supposed to be? (void *) Missing *?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct answer:

```
void *jouer(void *arg);
int joueur=0;

for(joueur=0;joueur<nombre_joueurs;joueur++)
        {

        affiche();
        int *joueur = malloc(sizeof(*joueur));
        pthread_create(&threads[threads[nombre_joueurs]], NULL, jouer, (int *) joueur); 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the value of the variable, it expects the address.

You can't pass `joueur`'s address to `pthread_create()` as the data parameter because it's a local variable and it will be deallocated when the function returns, which might happen before the thread finishes working.

I would suggest

```
int *joueur = malloc(sizeof(*joueur));
if (joueur == NULL)
    doNotStartTheThread_ProblemAllocatingMemory();
pthread_create(&threads[joueur], NULL, jouer, (void *) joueur);
```

note that above, the type of `joueur` is `int *`, in your example it's `int *` you can't pass that to the `pthread_create()` function just by casting it to `void *` because it's interpreted as an address, and I doubt that `3` will be a valid one.

Don't forget to free `joueur` when the thread is done working with the poitner, because you can't free it before or the same problem will happen.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answer.

 But i am a beginner...

If I have understood the problem was the void *
 your lines 2 and 3 are just in case of allocating problems

 I have tried with this:

int *joueur = malloc(sizeof(*joueur));
//if (joueur == NULL)
    //doNotStartTheThread_ProblemAllocatingMemory();
pthread_create(&threads[joueur], NULL, jouer, (int *) joueur); 

But i have this message now. Excuse me for being slow it is because i needed to do google search to understand your answer.

Comment: @NouhaLa (e iharob): The error is the result of `jouer` having the wrong type. A thread function must take a `void*` argument (not `int` nor `int*`) and it *must* return `void*`. A function which returns nothing (i.e. `void`) is incompatible with the parameter in `pthread_create`.

Comment: @rici You are right, I didn't see the declaration of `jouer()`, but it's worng.